# Reading a passed XML file directly in PHP

Tags: php, xml, forms

So a form like this:

```
<form action="/appapi/checkout/" method="post" mimetype="text/xml" enctype="text/xml" name="form1">
<input type="file" name="xmlfile">
<br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Will pass me a xml file to `appapi/checkout/`

How can I read this file? Or do I need to save it on my server before I can read it?

Like it has been done here: [receive xml file via post in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938811/receive-xml-file-via-post-in-php)

I tried to:

```
$url = 'php://input';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

But wouldnt work out. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not specifically sure that `enctype="text/xml"` in the `<form>` element will make the browser to send in the file's content as raw input to the server. One might want to test if that's possible, but I don't know.

However, you could perform a [standard file upload with PHP<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and work on the temporary file that will be automatically created:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['xmlfile']['tmp_name']);
```

This needs the form to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Also it's wise to first check if the file was successfully uploaded by looking into `$_FILES['xmlfile']['error']`, it is `0` when no error occured:

```
$upload = (object) $_FILES['xmlfile'];
$xml = $upload->error ? NULL : simplexml_load_file($upload->tmp_name);
```

BTW, the tempfile will be automatically removed when the PHP script finishes.

Answer (score 1):

First, fix the HTML.

1. `<form>` has no `mimetype` attribute. Remove it.
2. The `enctype` attribute [does not accept `text/xml` as a value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-enctype) replace it with `multipart/form-data`
3. The `name` attribute is pointless unless you need to access the form with JavaScript, in which case use an `id` instead.

Since you are using PHP, the file will then appear in [`$_FILES[]`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) read it from there.